# Best practice for maintaining the order of a subset of records

Tags: python, mysql, database

I am trying to implement a playlist, and right now I come up with these tables:

```
   playlist
     id
     title
     creator

   playlist_item
     id
     item_id
     playlist_id
     position

   item
     id
     title
```

When I try to write `Playlist.add_song`, I found it hard to maintain the order of items with `position`.

I have to know what the last position is to set the position of the new record `last position + 1`.

What would be a better way to implement this?

Comment: Change it to `added_on` and write the current timestamp (with mili/microseconds). This way you can sort safely.

Comment: @eumiro, the order can be arranged by the owner, so I can't just solve it by ordering by `added_on`.

Answer (score 0):

I remember doing the same thing for an mp3 player i wrote some years ago. The problem is not just setting a new position, but also updating positions if a playlist item is deleted (one that was in the middle, for instance, then all below must be updated).

Since a good implementation commands that your positions are numbered sequentially, without gaps, i would say that you could just get the count of playlist items + 1, to identify the position of a new record.

Comment: "Since a good implementation commands that your positions are numbered sequentially, without gaps" Positions don't need to be numbered without gaps internally. They don't even need to be *numbered* internally, as long as there's some other way to order them. Position order and position enumeration are two different things, and you have less trouble when you keep them separate.

Comment: "As long as there is another way to order them" would be a good statement, if there was a way. The only one that is already there is id and, of course, that's a very bad practice. I don't understand why you would ever need a position order and a position enumeration as two different things, to tell you the truth. A position index would be just enough for everything in a playlist. As long as an item has the number 3, it's the third one to be played. Now, if you just want to add items with incrementing numbers, it's a matter of taste, i suppose.

Comment: The thing is that the item with index = 47823612 being the 4th one to be played, is quite cumbersome. If you  don't want a position index, though, you can use the date to do it i suppose. Still, you would need another field, but the handling is easier.

Comment: "I don't understand why you would ever need a position order and a position enumeration as two different things" Because enumeration, as displayed to the user, seems to require a sequence of integers without gaps. That probably means updating almost all the keys when someone puts a song 3rd or 4th. (Nobody raises a song from 101 to 100, do they?) On the other hand, order doesn't require integers, and it doesn't mind gaps.  If you order by a float, for example, you can insert anywhere without updating.

Comment: Well, people can raise songs from 101 to 100(or other) many times. I'm pretty sure that you have done it as well(i have also). When you create a reordering routine, you cannot be based on such assumptions. If you do not want to use an increasing index, i would highly suggest checking the timestamp.